# Return value of iteration over array

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, return-value

I'm trying to build a music library.

My main problem is when I iterate over the array with the #each method the return value is huge knowing that my array is all the albums and songs about one artist.

Would you know a way to iterate over arrays with a return value of `nil` or at least way shorter than the entire artist array I created?

Comment: So you iterate over an array to do something and you want to return nil? correct? and why?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? can you share some code?

Comment: I'm curious too

Comment: Are you under the impression that `each` is creating a copy of the array that it is enumerating? That's what it seems like your concern is, and that is not the case.

Comment: It's better to share actual code.

Answer (score 4):

Just return `nil` after the iteration if you don't want the collection as a return value.

```
def your_method
  your_collection.each do |item|
    # do something
  end
  nil
end
```

Comment: `each` returns the thing it was operating on, it doesn't copy it, but it can be really annoying to see this in `irb`. Equivalent: `x.map { ... }; nil`

Comment: @tadman are you sure your comment is meant for my answer? I never talked about copy

Comment: Your method works well in code, but for a one-liner as you'd do in `irb` you need a slightly different approach. The copy part is in relation to some of the confusion in the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Compact method will eliminate `nil` values, if that is what you mean.

```
['foo', nil, 'bar'].compact.each do |part|
    puts part
end

=> foo
   bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `&& nil` after your expression:

```
myarray.each {....} && nil
```